# prompt user in a bash process subsitution

Tags: bash

I have a bash script using [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`< <`) to continuously display the result of a long process.

```
while read -r LINE
do
  something
done < <( unbuffer my_long_running_script)
```

I would like to ask for user input in between.

```
while read -r LINE
do
  something
  ASK_THE_USER
done < <( unbuffer my_long_running_script)
```

I tried with basic `select` or `read` but the result of `my_long_running_script` is still comming in and is taken as a reply (and therefore invalid).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -u 3 -r line; do
  echo "$line" # something
  read -p "Continue?" -r response
  [[ $response == 'y' ]] || break
done 3< <(unbuffer my_long_running_script)
```

Sending the process substitution (`<(...)`) as input to custom file descriptor `3` (`3<`) leaves stdin free to read from the terminal.

`-u 3` makes `read` read from that descriptor.